# Prevent to navigate back until user answer AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have an iOS app and now I am porting it to the Android with Kotlin. But I stucked in very simple case. 
There is an EditText in a Fragment and I want to ask user does he/she wants to save before leaving the fragment if something had written to the EditText.

I can handle back button with `OnBackPressedCallback` and `handleOnBackPressed` and show user the AlertDialog but fragment closes without waiting the users answer. But I don't want this, isn't possible to wait user's answer and then popUpTo previous fragment? Because I have to save the text before the fragment close.

Here is my code

```
package info.airportnotes.maxipower.ui.note

import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.MainActivity
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.R
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.model.Status
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.utils.AirportNotesApp
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.utils.AppPreferences
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.utils.isNetworkAvailable
import info.airportnotes.maxipower.viewmodel.NewNoteViewModel


class NewNoteFragment : Fragment() {
    private var airportID: Long? = null
    private lateinit var viewModel: NewNoteViewModel
    private lateinit var builder : AlertDialog.Builder
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_note, container, false)
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title =  getString(R.string.new_note)
        viewModel =
            ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(NewNoteViewModel::class.java)
        airportID = arguments?.getLong("airportID") ?: 0
        viewModel.airportID = airportID
        viewModel.refresh()

        val fab: View = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.sendNote)
        if (!AppPreferences.isUserLoggedIn) {
            fab.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val noLoginBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as MainActivity)
            noLoginBuilder?.setMessage(getString(R.string.you_should_login))
                ?.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ok_title)) { _, _ ->

                }
            noLoginBuilder?.create()?.show()
        }
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val text = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.noteText)
            if(text.text.toString().isEmpty()) return@setOnClickListener
            if (AirportNotesApp.appContext.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                viewModel.addNote(
                    text.text.toString(),
                    airportID!!, viewModel.filteredLang.value?.Code!!, AppPreferences.userID,
                    onFinish = {
                        it?.let {
                            if (it.status == Status.Success) {
                                Toasty.success(
                                    AirportNotesApp.appContext,
                                    getString(R.string.your_note_added),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                    true
                                ).show();

                                if (AppPreferences.preferredLanguage.isNullOrEmpty() ||
                                    (AppPreferences.preferredLanguage.isNullOrBlank() && !AppPreferences.preferredLanguage.contentEquals(
                                        viewModel.filteredLang.value?.Code.toString()
                                    ))
                                ) {
                                    val yesNoBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as MainActivity)
                                    val lang = viewModel.filteredLang.value?.Title
                                    yesNoBuilder?.setMessage(
                                            resources.getString(
                                                R.string.ask_for_preferred_lang,
                                                lang
                                            )
                                        )
                                        ?.setPositiveButton(
                                            getString(R.string.yes_please)
                                        ) { _, _ ->
                                            AppPreferences.preferredLanguage =
                                                viewModel.filteredLang.value?.Code.toString()
                                            view.findNavController().popBackStack()
                                        }?.setNegativeButton(
                                            getString(R.string.no_i_dont_want)
                                        ) { _, _ ->
                                            view.findNavController().popBackStack()
                                        }
                                    yesNoBuilder?.create()?.show()
                                }
                                else {
                                    view.findNavController().popBackStack()
                                }

                            } else {
                                Toasty.error(
                                    AirportNotesApp.appContext,
                                    it.message,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                    true
                                ).show();
                                view.findNavController().popBackStack()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            else{
                Toasty.warning(view.context, AirportNotesApp.appContext.getString(R.string.no_internet_add_note), Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show()
            }
        }
        builder = this.context?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }!!
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.filterByBtn).setOnClickListener{ view ->
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()
        }

        val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                //TODO "Dialog kapanmadan , navigationı durdurmanın yolunu bul"
                val note = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.noteText)
                if(note.text.isNotEmpty()){
                    if( viewModel.draftNote.value != null){
                        val draft = viewModel.draftNote.value!!
                        val yesNoBuilder =AlertDialog.Builder(activity as MainActivity)
                        yesNoBuilder?.setMessage(getString(R.string.do_u_want_to_keep_your_draft))
                            ?.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes_keep_it_please)
                            ) { _, _ ->
                                draft.Text = note.text.toString()
                                viewModel.updateDraftNote(draft)

                            }?.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no_delete_it_please)
                            ) { _, _ ->
                                viewModel.deleteDraft(airportID!!)
                                viewModel.deleteNotification()

                            }
                        yesNoBuilder?.setCancelable(false)
                        yesNoBuilder?.create()?.show()
                    }
                    else{
                        val yesNoBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as MainActivity)
                        yesNoBuilder?.setMessage(getString(R.string.do_you_want_to_save_your_note_as_draft))
                            ?.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes_save_it_please)
                            ) { _, _ ->
                                val noteText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.noteText)
                                var lang = ""
                                if(viewModel.filteredLang.value != null) {
                                    lang = viewModel.filteredLang.value!!.Code
                                }
                                viewModel.addNoteDraft(noteText.text.toString(), airportID!!, lang)
                            }?.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no_delete_it_please)
                            ) { _, _ ->

                            }
                        yesNoBuilder?.setCancelable(false)
                        yesNoBuilder?.create()?.show()
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if( viewModel.draftNote.value != null) {

                        val yesNoBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as MainActivity)
                        yesNoBuilder?.setMessage(getString(R.string.do_u_want_to_keep_your_draft))
                            ?.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes_keep_it_please)
                            ) { _, _ ->

                            }?.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no_delete_it_please)
                            ) { _, _ ->
                                viewModel.deleteDraft(airportID!!)
                                viewModel.deleteNotification()

                            }
                        yesNoBuilder?.setCancelable(false)
                        yesNoBuilder?.create()?.show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)

        observeViewModel(view)
        return view
    }

    private fun observeViewModel(view: View?) {
        viewModel.languages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { languages ->
            languages?.let {
                val list = ArrayList<String>()
                for (l in languages){
                    list.add(l.Title)
                }
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_a_language))?.setItems(list.toTypedArray(),
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                        viewModel.filteredLang.value = languages[which]
                        if(languages[which].Title != "All") {
                            val lang = languages[which].Title
                            val yesNoBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as MainActivity)
                            yesNoBuilder?.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.ask_for_preferred_lang, lang))
                                ?.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes_please)
                                ) { _, _ ->
                                    AppPreferences.preferredLanguage = languages[which].Code
                                }?.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no_i_dont_want)
                                ) { _, _ ->
                                    // User cancelled the dialog
                                }
                            yesNoBuilder?.create()?.show()
                        }
                        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                    })
            }
        })

        viewModel.filteredLang.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{lang ->
            lang?.let {
                view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.filterByBtn)?.text = getString(R.string.selected_language, lang.Title)
            }
        })
        viewModel.draftNote.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{note ->
            note?.let {
                val text = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.noteText)
                text?.setText(note.Text)
            }
        })
        viewModel.addResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{result ->
            result?.let {

            }

        })
    }

}
```

I read dozens of pages about this and tried most of it but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you check your onPause method are you doing any fragment transaction there?

Comment: use yesNoBuilder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

Comment: @HappySingh i don't have any onPause method in any of my fragments. Should i have?

Comment: @BhanuPrakashPasupula thank you but unfortunately i couldn't understand why should i set this property. Yes this can help me to improve UX but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @bahadirarslan can you put more code of your fragment so I can have a better understanding

Comment: @HappySingh here is the full code of my fragment. it looks like a little bit messy but i hope you can find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that mishandled onOptionsItemSelected function in MainActivity causing this. Similiar problem occured at options menu so I could find the cause.

Here is the mishandled version

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        if (menuItem != null) {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
    }
```

And here is the correct version

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    val id = menuItem?.itemId
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
}
```